# How can every $p$-adic integer be the limit of a sequence of non-negative integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

See [Andrew Baker's P-adic Notes](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~ajb/dvi-ps/padicnotes.pdf#page=28&zoom=150,0,556).  Every element of $\mathbb{Z}_p = \{a \in \mathbb{Q}_p : |a|_p \leq 1 \}$ is a limit of a sequence of non-negative integers, with respect to the $|\cdot|_p$ norm.  How is this possible?

Comment: Take the partial sums of its standard power series.

Comment: Are $-p^k(a/b)$ and $p^k(a/b)$ identified in $Q_p$?

Comment: no, but weirdly -1 is a sum of infinitely many positive integers. $$-1 = \sum_{i=0}^\infty (p-1) p^i$$

Comment: You mean in $Z$? So the partial sums have limit -1.

Comment: Yes, though the infinite sum only converges when considered as happening $\mathbb{Z}_p$, it just so happens that every partial sum and the final infinite sum all lie in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You can think of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as being sequences $\displaystyle (a_n)\in\prod_n (\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})$ where $a_n\equiv a_m\text{ mod }p^m$ for $m\leqslant n$. The integers sit inside of here as the set of all such sequences that are eventually constant. Do you see how to approximate now? the ability to use non-negative integers comes from the fact that in every $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ the image of $x\in\mathbb{Z}_-$ is equal to the image of some $y\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0}$.

Comment: Yes this is a better proof IMO.  It's easy to show that your map is a ring isomorphism.  And I can almost work out that the image of each negative integer is the image of some positive one.

Comment: Do you know a good reference that talks more about this type of p-adic analysis?

Comment: @EnjoysMath Uhm, a lot of places talk about it--not many of them provide intuition for why you'd expect $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as I defined it (an inverse limit of the $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$) is actually the completion of $\mathbb{Z}$ with respect to $v_p$. Are you looking for intuition, or just facts?